# ionic 3, android page up when using keyboard and back

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard

ionic 3, when I use keyboard, all pages going up when I back. How can i solve this issue. If nav push it s okay but when i nav pop it s happen.

keyboard mode on
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRypd.png

first page
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8LzM.png

this one is when i back second page to first one
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B23H.png

this is my app.module for this issue

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
scrollPadding:false,
scrollAssist:false})
```

ionic version : 3.10.0,

cordova version : 7.0.1,

node version : 6.11.3,

```
 platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();

 this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
});
```

}